# vee validate is not working with vue.js version 1.0.28

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

**Versions:**

VueJs: version 1.0.28

Vee-Validate: any version

**Description:**

I am using vue js version 1.0.28 in my project. Now i want to use vee validate with vue js. But i am getting vee validation compatibility issue with vue js version 1.0.28. Now i am not able to update vue js  version.  Can any one give any solution?

```
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html
http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/
```

If I use vue js version 2.X then vee validate works but not with 1.0.28.

Comment: What version of Vee Validate are you using? A wild guess but I'll put my 5 cents on [Vee Validate 1.x](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.11) being compatible with Vue.js 1.x.

Comment: There is no restriction for vee validate version i have tried different versions of vee validate but not success full.